# How to use NDSolve with moving boundary conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

So I am trying to solve the movement in space and time of a spreading gravity current. The interface satisfies the following PDE:

$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(h^3 \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right) $.

The nose, $h(x,t) = 0$, of the current can move forward in space. If we say the initial condition is $h(x,0) = 1-x$, then the nose, $x_N$ is initially at $x = 1$. The base of the current can be fixed at $h(0,t) = 1$. So I have one IC and one BC, I need another BC to close the system. Now, as time moves forward the nose (fixed at h = 0) propagates according to the expression:

$\int_0^{x_N} h \,  dx = \frac{1}{2} + t$

or kinematically $\dot{x_N} = -h^2 h_x$.

Clearly the second boundary condition in $x$ needs to come from the nose condition, but I have no idea how to input an integral boundary condition or the kinematic condition. Secondly, I have no idea how to deal with xmax in NDSolve as clearly my xmax is moving forward with each time step.

Here is my attempt, which gives a "There are fewer dependent variables error"

```
NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] == D[h[x, t]^3 D[h[x, t], x], x], h[0, t] == 1,
h[x, 0] == 1 - x (D[h[x, t], t] /. x -> 1) == -h[x, t]^2 (D[h[x, t], x] /. 
  x -> 1)}, h, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

**EDIT**

So I solved this problem by amending the code in this [Stefan problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/pde-with-stefan-conditions-a-k-a-variable-boundary/58622?noredirect=1#comment313272_58622) post. I modified the statement of the problem slightly to work more closely to @ybeltukov excellent solution, and actually solved the following system:

$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(h^3 \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right) \\ \dot{s} = -h^2 h_x \\ s(0) = 0 \\ h(x,0) = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{for } x = 0  \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\
h(s(t),t) = 0 \\
h(0,t) = 1
$.

I made the same change to a normalised variable for my PDE and then amended finite difference code:

```
n = 100;
\[Delta]\[Xi] = 1./n;

ClearAll[dv, t];
dv[v_List] := 
With[{s = First@v, u = Rest@v}, 
With[{ds = u[[-1]]^3/(s \[Delta]\[Xi]), \[Xi] = N@Range[n - 1]/n, 
 d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/\[Delta]\[Xi], #] &, 
 d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/\[Delta]\[Xi]^2, #] &}, 
Prepend[3 u^2 d1[#]^2/s^2 + u^3 d2[#]/s^2 + \[Xi] ds d1[#]/s &@
  Join[{1}, u, {0.}], ds]]];
 s0 = 0.001;
 v0 = Flatten@Prepend[ConstantArray[0.001, n - 2], {s0, 1.}];
 sol = NDSolve[{v'[t] == dv[v[t]], v[0] == v0}, v, {t, 0, 50}][[1, 1, 
2]];
```

Returning from the normalised variable is identical code.

You can then make a nice time series with this code:

```
ListAnimate[
Table[Plot[u[t, x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 3}}], {t, 
 0, 50, 0.1}]]
```

Which returns a spreading current as desired.

[image: Spreading viscous gravity current]

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by the kinematic condition $\dot{x}_N=-h^2h_x$? Do I understand correctly that the right-hand-side should be evaluated at $x=0$? or at $x=x_N$ (for which it vanishes)?

Comment: Also, your initial condition is inconsistent with the integral constraint because at $t=0$ you have
$$\int_0^{x_N} h\, dx=\int_0^1(1-x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\ne t=0$$

Comment: Similar to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109201/piecewise-function-on-boundary-condition/109307#109307

Comment: @ojlm  I'm not sure if your statements about the moving nose are correct. You might wish to consult my solution, and particularly the steady state solution.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze The nose needs to propagate downstream as this is a model for a fluid mechanical process. Pinning the interface to the bottom boundary at x=1 is not physically what happens. I have given a link to a paper in my other comment. Governing equations are on page 3. I have simplified the propagation flux condition as I am only considering a one layered spreading current in this model.

Comment: @yohbs Technically kinematic condition is $\dot{x_N} = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_N} \left(h^2 h_x\right)$. Easier to understand that the volume $ \int_0^{x_N} h \,  dx$ is increasing with time as fluid enters from the left and the interface propagates down stream. Understand about IC inconsistency. I have amended it to be consistent. The true initial condition should be x = 0, but I wanted to avoid infinite gradients.

Comment: What would you like to model with this initial condition: `h[x, 0] == 
 1 - x (D[h[x, t], t] /. x -> 1) == -h[x, t]^2 (D[h[x, t], x] /. 
    x -> 1)`? There are two `==`

Comment: @user21 I want to incorporate the fact that the point of contact h = 0, can move away from its initial location x = 1, downstream, with respect to the condition $ \int_0^{x_N(t)} h \,  dx = t$. My problem is that you have to select an xmax, so I need to move the computational domain at each time step. And also how to incorporate an integral boundary condition.

Comment: @yohbs Governing equations are on page 3 of this paper. My equation is simplified as I only have one layer. My goal is to be able to get a time series of the current propagating downstream. https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/247602/Kowal%20et%20al%202015%20Journal%20of%20Fluid%20Mechanics.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Which of the two equations should hold at `t==0`? It is an initial condition for `h[x,0]`. If you which to make a parametric study on the initial conditions, then you could have a look at `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze thanks for all your help. A solution for the time series is provided above.

Answer (score 4):

The PDE can be easily solved numerically if a simple additional boundary condition is imposed.

Adding a second bundary condition h[1,t] = 0 we find numerically, without any error message

```
hh[x_, t_] = 
  h[x, t] /. 
   NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] == D[h[x, t]^3 D[h[x, t], x], x], h[0, t] == 1, 
      h[1, t] == 0, h[x, 0] == (1 - x)}, h[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];

Plot3D[hh[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Solution of a PDE", AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "h[x,t]"}]
```

[image]

Executing NDSolve without a secod boundary condition leads to about the same graph and the error message that a second boundary condition is missing.

The time dependence at various positions is given by the graph

```
Plot[{hh[0.2, t], hh[0.5, t], hh[0.8, t], hh[0.95, t]}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Solution of a PDE\nTime dependence for various locations x = 1 - h[x,0]", 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "h[x,t]"}]
```

[image]

The asymptotic function for large t is given by

```
ha[x_] = (1 - x)^(1/4)
```

which solves the steady state ODL derived from the original PDE.

We could study the approch of the solution to the equlibirum by linearizing the equation, i.e. letting

```
h = hL[x] + ha[x]
```

and dropping all non linear terms in hL.

Partial solutions are given by Bessel functions. The interested reader will surely be able to follow this path on his own.

*Moving structures*

Let us have a look at moving structures allowed by the PDE.

Letting

```
h[x,t] = g[x - v t]
```

The PDE reduces to an ODE which can be solved

```
gg[x_] = g[x] /. 
   DSolve[g'[x] v == 3 g[x]^2 g'[x]^2 + g[x]^3 g''[x], g[x], x][[1]] /. 
  C[2] -> 0

(* Out[341]= InverseFunction[-((C[1]^3 Log[C[1] + v #1])/v^4) + (C[1]^2 #1)/v^3 - (
    C[1] #1^2)/(2 v^2) + #1^3/(3 v) &][x] *)
```

Defining

```
h1[s_] = (gg[x][[0, 1]] /. {C[1] -> -10, v -> 1} // FullSimplify)@s

(* Out[393]= 100 s + 5 s^2 + s^3/3 + 1000 Log[-10 + s] *)
```

Gives

```
Plot[Re[h1[s]], {s, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 3540}, 
 PlotLabel -> "'Nose' profile", AxesLabel -> {"x - t", "g"}]
```

[image]

This section is just a sketch which must be worked out more thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know it's possible to solve the PDE with h[1,t] = 0 boundary condition. However, since this is the propagation of a current, the nose needs to move over the bottom boundary. I want to be able to to create a time series such that the current moves along down the x axis.

If you see this paper, you can see how the current propgates down the x-axis as time progresses. Having the h[1,t] = 0 boundary condition does not allow me this. https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/247602/Kowal%20et%20al%202015%20Journal%20of%20Fluid%20Mechanics.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: I appreciate your further analysis about travelling wave solutions. This problem is well known and the best way to study it analytically is via a similarity solution. However, the point is I am using this model in an illustrative way. I am studying a much harder system, that has an interface moving transiently along a boundary. The key thing I am interested in do is to create a time series of the spreading thinning profile as seen in the paper I sent. Would you be able to help me in achieving this? I want to be have the profile spreading and thinning with accordance to the volume BC